# Latex - set caption font to 11pt?

Tags: latex

According to stackoverflow and http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/float/caption.pdf I am able to change font of figure caption like:

```
\usepackage[font={normal,it}]{caption}
```

but how to set it for particular fontsize value directly?

I would expect something like

```
\usepackage[font={11,it}]{caption}
```

or

```
\usepackage[font={11pt,it}]{caption}
```

but it throws errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LaTeX you set the document font size at the beginning and then elsewhere use keywords to resize the font relative to the given size. Here is a [list of LaTex relative font sizes](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles#Reference_guide). So if you used the following `documentclass` command

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

then you would use `small` to get a smaller font in your captions:

```
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I could redefine the size of one of the relative font sizes for desired value, and use it for caption.

Comment: Do not do this! The font sizes are carefully matched. If you use 12pt as main font size, small is pretty close to 11pt: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc